# Adding months together or working in base 12

Tags: excel, excel-2007, radix

I'm a teaching assistant for a school working with kids with special needs and I've been asked to produce a spreadsheet that can keep track of their reading ages and spelling ages as they progress through the school. They have two tests per year, about every 6 months, so I'm using a column for the test result and the adjacent column for their improvement over their last test.

However, in order for the improvement to work properly, I need to get the cells from H2 to (for example) V20 to work in base 12 so i can perform functions on it. I've found a way of converting the output of a call to display in base 12, but that's all I can use it for - Base 12.

An example of how I've got it now would be as follows:

Reading age after year 7 test 1 - 7
Reading age after year 7 test 2 - 7.2 (not 7.2 years, 7 years and 2months.)
Reading age after year 8 test 1 - 7.8 (again, 7 years and 8 months)
Reading age after year 8 test 2 - 7.11 (so rather than being 7 units, 1 tenth and 1 hundredth, it would be 7 years and 11 months)

The formula to work out the improvement on per test is as follows:

> =IF(OR(ISBLANK(H2),ISBLANK(I2))," ",(I2-H2))

My issue is getting the cells within this area to work (or think?) as if they are working with months, rather than decimals.

Comment: You should make 2 columns one titled Year. Then one titled Test Number.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you need to use 7.01 for 7 years 1 month so that you can distinguish between that and 7.10 (7 years 10 months). If you use that approach then you can use DOLLARDE and DOLLARFR functions to handle base 12, e.g.

`=IF(COUNT(H2,I2)=2,DOLLARFR(DOLLARDE(I2,12)-DOLLARDE(H2,12),12),"")`